# Replace Formula in a cell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a cell of `C6`, it's current value is formula of `C5/C4`, I want to change the formula to `If(C4=0, 0, C5/C4)`.

I have many cells similar to this cell, that's why I want to develop a macro so I can loop through them.

However, the code below does not work. I think the problem is `Divider=0` in the last line. Because if I replace this part directly with `C4=0`, the code will work.

can someone advise me what would be the correct code? Thanks in advance!

```
Sub replaceingError()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Dim StrTemp As String
  Dim Divider As String
  StrTemp = ws.Range("c6").formula
  MsgBox (StrTemp) 
  Divider = Right(StrTemp, 2)
  MsgBox (Divider)
  ws.Range("c6").value = "=IF(Divider=0, 0, strTemp)"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a concatenation of the new formula parts with variables value:

```
Sub replaceingError()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sDivider As String
    Dim sFormula As String

    Set oWS = ActiveSheet
    sTemp = oWS.Range("C6").Formula
    sDivider = Right(sTemp, 2)
    sTemp = Mid(sTemp, 2)
    sFormula = "=IF(" & sDivider & "=0,0," & sTemp & ")"
    oWS.Range("C6").Formula = sFormula

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `.Value` to set formula

Correct syntax is `.Formula`

`ws.Range("c6").Formula = "=IF(" & Divider & "=0, 0, strTemp)"`

Comment: It does not work? What I got is: #NAME?, and the cell value is: =IF(Divider=0, 0, strTemp)

Comment: because you dont have a named range `Divider` in your workbook.

Comment: @cyboashu `Divider` shouldn't be a named range in worksheet since it's a VBA project variable.